# ProgressBar get Stucked at 0% while downloading file from server?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I am creating an Android application to download an mp3 file from
server. The downloading is working fine. But the `ProgressBar` is
stuck at 0% while downloading...

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // button to show progress dialog
    Button btnShowProgress;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ImageView my_image;
    // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    // File url to download
    private static String file_url = "http://eecindia.co.in/up/01%20-%20Pretham%20-%20Oruthikku%20Pinnil%20[Maango.me].mp3";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // show progress bar button
        btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
        // Image view to show image after downloading
        my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        /**
         * Show Progress bar click event
         * */
        btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // starting new Async Task
                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case progress_bar_type:
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
                return pDialog;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to download file
     * */
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.mp3");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
           // String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.mp3";
            // setting downloaded into image view
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloaded Succesfully.. check SD card 2 see file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You override onCreateDialog(). In which class?. Of which class is showDialog() a member?

Comment: in onProgressUpdate() method put log for progress[0] and check what values are comming (are you getting values other than zero?)

Answer (score 0):

the above process works fine for image files but gets stuck for large files then you have to change this code in doinbackground method and see ..it works :)

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD"); 
connection.connect(); 
int length = connection.getContentLength();
```